# How to create a more specific redirect rule in .htaccess file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a redirect in my `.htaccess` file that looks like this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 (?i)/my-path/?$ https://www.targetsite.com/
```

So this works great for redirecting to this:
`www.site.com/my-path`

Problem is that this is also catching: `www.site.com/about/my-path`

How can I write a redirect that **only redirects**

```
www.site.com/my-path
```

but not

```
www.site.com/about/my-path
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply remove `(?i)` it's not valid anyway, and add `^`

`RedirectMatch 301 ^/my-path/?$ https://www.targetsite.com/`

Comment: Thank you! So '^' matches the beginning of a string. So if my rewrite base is / then ^/my-path/ will only match base/my-path and not base/other-path/my-path/. Got it. I was using '(?!)' at the beginning to make my redirects case-insensitive. I'll just need to figure out how to do that with the '^'.